# Is it possible to determine From number used when using copilot messaging service

Tags: c#, twilio

When i send a text to a customer using a messaging service id.  The from number is null in the returned MessageResource. Code below.

Is the only way to determine the From by making an additional call out using the message sid?  I need the from used for analytics and so I can use the same number to contact an account in case the customer uses multiple contact numbers.

```
return await MessageResource.CreateAsync
            (
                to: new PhoneNumber(toNumber),
                messagingServiceSid: messengerSid,
                body: message                    
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you use a messaging service to send messages from various numbers then you cannot know at the time of message creation what the number used will be. When you make the request to send the message, Twilio queues that message up to be delivered by the messaging service. If you inspect the status of the message object you receive from the API call you show in your question you will see it is "accepted". At this point the messaging service won't have decided which number to use.

So, you can either make a second request to the API using the message SID that is returned to find out the `From` number. Or, you could set a [`StatusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional) which would receive a request once the message was sent, including the From number.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using the status callback and api calls to get the number.